# jQuery Mobile on PhoneGap - List Example Looks bad, components overlaps

Tags: iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I just downloaded PhoneGap to try it. I made an XCode Project and it's working alright.  Then, I wanted to try some jQuery Mobile on it, so added this to the default Hello World Page of Cordoba:

I added, to the **head**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

And then on the **body**:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
  <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
</ul>
```

I thought it would go fine, but look how it comes out:

[image]

Here's all the code in case you want to take a look at it. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received"><a href="#" id="devReadyAnchor">Device is Ready</a></p>
            </div>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
                <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the

```
    <div data-role="content">
```

wrapping the list. That was all.

Here's all the code in case it's useful for someone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">

                <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>

                </div>
            <div>
                <h1>Some text</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
                <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```